# подключение библиотек и шрифтов по ссылке из интернета

Tags: javascript, html, браузер

я заметил что если подключить шрифтов и библиотек по ссылке из интернета потом отключить интернет и перезагрузить компьютер и потом снова открыть HTML файл то все шрифты и библиотеки работают по ссылке без интернета, даже если скопировать ссылки в другой HTML файл там тоже работает. Хотел спросить например я подключил jQuery и отключил интернет тогда где сохраняется коды jQuery ? может в файле HTML ? или в браузере ? или в операционной системе ? и насколько долго может хранится коды ?

Comment: это называется браузерный кеш

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Браузер использует кэширование на основе заголовков запросов. Если кэширование разрешено, браузер запомнит скрипт и не будет его повторно загружать, пока время кэша не истечет или пользователь принудительно его не обновит. Вот небольшая статья о кэше https://habr.com/ru/post/203548/